# Replace carriage returns SOQL API

Tags: sql, soql, azure-data-factory

I am using Azure data factory to extract data from Salesforce API connector. Problem is some of the data contains carriage returns and line feeds.

Normally I would use `REPLACE(REPLACE(column, char(10),''),char(13),'')` but doesn't seem to work with SOQL.

The actual query fails, although I can replace characters if I specify quotes, I have tried various escape characters too ` ' " \ / but nothing seems to work

Does anyone know a way to strip out carriage returns and line feeds?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're trying to get carriage returns AND line feeds, don't you need to do REPLACE(REPLACE(column, char(10), ''),char(13),'')

Comment: yes but it fails in SOQL you can replace characters in quotes, tried various escape characters ` ' " \ / but nothing seems to work.

Comment: It seems that SOQL doesn't support a REPLACE function (reference: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/61099/how-to-use-replace-function-in-salesforce-soap-api-in-c).  You may be able to use the workaround here (https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008zIRIAY)